# Are Graph and Group Isomorphism problems random self-reducible?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, graph-isomorphism, gr.group-theory, average-case-complexity, worst-case

Are Graph and Group Isomorphism problems known to be random self-reducible? If so is there a good proof?

Are there other non-trivial examples of random self-reducibility? Is there a good reference?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "random self-reducible"?

Comment: @Kaveh Something along lines of Dlog or permanent like in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_self-reducibility

Comment: So you want to reduce the problem of deciding if graph $G$ is isomorphic to $H$ to deciding isomorphism on $m = \textrm{poly}(n)$ pairs $(G_1, H_2), \ldots, (G_m, H_m)$ where each $(G_i, H_i)$ is distributed uniformly over all pairs of graphs on n vertices? This makes little sense since a uniformly distributed pair of graphs is non-isomorphic with very high probability. Do you mean something else? (As has been pointed out before, you should think harder before asking questions.)

Comment: @SashoNikolov In here https://books.google.com/books?id=jKEEeScADuMC&pg=PA98&lpg=PA98&dq="graph+isomorphism"+"random+self+reducible" it is stated graph isomorphism is random self reducible. What does it mean here?

Comment: It's the notion from this paper http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/SFCS.1987.49. The reduction takes $(G, H)$ and outputs $(G, H')$, where $H'$ is $H$ with the vertices uniformly permuted. This reduces GI to distinguishing between the cases (1) $H$ is a uniform graph from the isomorphism class of $G$; (2) $G$ and $H$ are not isomorphic. But this is not a reduction to uniform instances of GI. The question is, what notion of random self-reducability do *you* want, *precisely*?

Comment: I am thinking following. Suppose we have can find isomorphism of pairs ${(G_i,\sigma(G_i))}$ for 1/log(total isomorphic classes) in poly time (with condition that no two of pairs are isomorphic to each other) for any $\sigma\in S_n$ would it be possible to deduce isomorphism between any arbitrary pair (G,H) if one exists and decide not if one does not exist from the polynomially many in list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Graph Isomorphism is randomly self-reducible in the sense of the question (clarified in the comments), then it could be solved in poly time. The reason is that there is in fact an average-case *linear time* algorithm for GI (even a canonical form) [BK].

For Group Isomorphism, this is not known. However, it's also somewhat of a funny question, because of how much the group order can restrict the structure of a group. In many senses, most groups are of order $2^k$, and are nilpotent of class 2. I find it hard to see how one would get a random self-reduction for GroupIso...

[BK]. Laszlo Babai, Ludik Kucera, [Canonical labelling of graphs in linear average time](http://doi.ieeecomputersociety.org/10.1109/SFCS.1979.8). FOCS 1979, pp.39-46.

Comment: I suppose even if they turn out to be rsr it will not have effects on other complexity classes?

Comment: That would be my guess, though of course one never knows where unexpected connections can occur...

Comment: could GI be random self reducible in following sense(1) and/or 2)). 1) For all isomorphism classes for all graph pairs in the same isomorphism class if you can figure out isomorphism for say 1/log(# elements in isomorphism class) in polynomial time then there is a randomized algorithm for graph isomorphism in polynomial time for every graph pair.

Comment: 2) For all pairs of isomorphism classes for all graph pairs in the with one member of pair per isomorphism class if you can figure out non-isomorphism for say 1/log(# pairs in the pairs of isomorphism class) in polynomial time then there is a randomized algorithm for graph non-isomorphism in polynomial time for every graph pair.